# Correlative in discontinuous ranges excel

Tags: excel

I have a doubt.
How can I assign numbers or correlative in discontinuous ranges?

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez4nx.png)

the idea is to repeat it until the space is detected, then continue but adding +1
for example:
Start with a correlative 1, then detect the space and automatically find the data again in 2 and thus increasing until the end of the list.
I'm using the formula

```
= YES (B2 = ""; ""; COUNTIF (B2; "<>") + MIN (0; C1))
```

the 2 that I show, is an example mode entered manually.
the idea is to automatically do so that it is quite rows interspersed with spaces

Answer (score 0):

If your words are in column B and the counting column is column C, then put 1 in C1 and then put

```
=IF(B2="","",IF(B1<>"",C1,MAX(C$1:C1)+1))
```

into C2 and drag copy it down column C.

Sample output:

```
B   C
X   1
Y   1

Z   2
W   2


P   3
Q   3
R   3
```